# Keyboard shortcut help for saving, I don't ctrl-s, I do alt, f, s

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, gui

I'm on Cinnamon Mint 20.  How do I get menu bars to stay active when I hit alt?  In windows, alt then f brings up the file menu, then I hit s to save.

In linux, the alt key is ignored unless I hold it down and hit f.  So I frequently end up just typing fs into a document.

Is there a setting somewhere to make alt engage the menu bar like it does in windows?

I am aware of ctrl-s, but that's not my 20 year old reflex.  I just roll my hand with my thumb hitting alt, index finger hitting f, then my ring finger smashing the s button.

Comment: What you describe is not ubiquitous behaviour on Linux. In the firefox I'm currently in `Alt` brings up the menu bar to stay (and it get focus so a following keypress moves to the right submenu), but in LIbreOffice it seems `Alt` only works as a modifier. So please specify the environment a little closer.